# Swift 3 How to get specific user id in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase as backend and I want all user id with status false.

[image: My Data]

What I am trying in my code:-

```
ref.child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("status").queryOrdered(byChild: "status").queryEqual(toValue : "false").observe(.value) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            print("SNAPSHOT: \(snapshot)")

            for snap in snapshot {
                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let key = snap.key
                    print(key)
                    print(postDict)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is status a Boolean? It may not be the problem, but the data types should match

Comment: yes status is boolean

Comment: which data type should match?

Comment: Then set the value to be a Boolean rather than a string, e.g  queryEqual(toValue: false). Like I said, this may not fix it, but give it a try and see what happens

Comment: Observer users node and iterate all users in for loop and check condition in user dictionary with matching condition status == false and if this condition satisfies, add userID to array.

Comment: @Paulo no it doesn't work

Comment: @VinitIngale can u please write this in code?

Comment: Hmmm, what error are you getting? That is a good shout Vinit, but if the poster has a large amount of data stored, this may have an impact on users data

Comment: @Paulo no error my snapshot in log is empty.Means no value in snapshot

Comment: What data are you trying to get? Are you looking for all users that have a status of false, or are you trying to see if the current user status is false?

Comment: @Paulo looking for all users that have a status of false

Comment: So, why are you looking into a child node of the current user?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159989/discussion-between-yash-r-and-paulo).

Comment: @YashR check below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find sample code below. Just verify syntax once.

```
   ref.child("users").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
        print("SNAPSHOT: \(snapshot)")

        for snap in snapshot {
            if let userDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

               if userDict["Status"] as? Bool == false {
               let key = snap.key
               print(key)
               //Add this key to userID array
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyObject?' and 'Bool' got this error

Comment: after debugging with breakpoints it does not goes inside the if statement of userDict

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159991/discussion-between-vinit-ingale-and-yash-r).