# Swift 4 TableView Cell not Displaying correct images

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

When I scroll the tableView the UIImageView is not displaying the correct image. How can I accomplish this correctly in the **swift 4 language.**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        //Transform Data From ^ to load at the bottom
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);
        cell?.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);
        cell?.accessoryView?.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);


        let username = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UITextView
        username.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].username

        let message = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UITextView
        message.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].message

        let timeStamp = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        timeStamp.text = messageArray[indexPath.row].timeStamp

        let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UIImageView
        let urlString = messageArray[indexPath.row].photoUrl
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        //Load profile image(on cell) with URL & Alamofire Library
        let downloadURL = NSURL(string: urlString!)
        imageView.af_setImage(withURL: downloadURL! as URL)

        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: U may get some better solution from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705286/reusable-cell-old-image-showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `imageView.image = nil` in the beginning of cellForRowAtIndexPath method. You are reusing cells. Sometimes you need to reset cell components.

Answer (score 1):

**Your solution**: Since cell is reusable so you need to update image every time when cell for calls.

**Best Practice**: I think you can do this think in much better way and avoid force unwrapping.

1. Use `SDWebCache` [https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage] pod for image downloading and cache as you every time calling same image via network request.
2. Use `Model` way to bind data with cell.

**Cell class**

```
import UIKit
import SDWebCache

public struct TableCellModel {
    var username: String
    var imageURL: String
    var messsage: String
    var timeStamp: String
}

class TableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var message: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeStamp: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    var item: Any? {
        didSet {
            self.configure(item)
        }
    }

    func configure(_ item: Any?) {
        if let model = item as? TableCellModel {
            self.username.text = model.username
            self.message.text = model.message
            self.timeStamp.text = model.timeStamp
            if let url = URL(model.imageURL) {
                self.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Assign this class to your tableview cell's custom class in storyboard
2. In your view controller declare `var cellItems: [TableCellModel] = []`
3. Initialize array in `viewDidLoad()` like

**In view Controller** : call this method in `viewDidLoad()`

```
func setupData() {
        self.cellItems =  [TableCellModel(username: "ABC", imageURL: "www....", message: "your message", timeStamp: "22.33.2222" ),
                            TableCellModel(username: "ABC", imageURL: "www....", message: "your message", timeStamp: "22.33.2222" ),
                            TableCellModel(username: "ABC", imageURL: "www....", message: "your message", timeStamp: "22.33.2222" ),
                            TableCellModel(username: "ABC", imageURL: "www....", message: "your message", timeStamp: "22.33.2222" )]

self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And tableView `cellforRow` delegate be like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableCell
    cell.item = self.cellItems[indexpath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using reusable cell here , it indeed `reuses` the cell with the old image. Then you need to update it every time the cell is shown in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! MenuTableViewCell
        //MARK:-  Show the image
        let imgName = "menu_\(indexPath.row + 1)"
        //MARK:- Disable the UITableView selection highlighting
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
```

You can set your image in your `Assets.xcassets`like this or any format you want-

[image]

Comment: Every user has a unique image is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: Are you using any id for the users?

Comment: This is not what im looking for.

Comment: Im not using 1 image. every image is different that was queried to a string.

Comment: first..are there any id for your users?

Comment: Then use the user id to show the specific image. Use if else inside the function

Comment: firstly, get the user id from firebase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530558/swift-3-how-to-get-specific-user-id-in-firebase . and then implement it in if else to show the specific image.