# Updating a single cell in UICollectionView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a problem with updating a single cell when using a UICollectionView.
When I click on a label I want the label to change to the value of a different number which I can assign manually.

Code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return nameArray.count;
    return 81;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell;

    switch(flattened[indexPath.item]){
    case 1:
        cell.labelText.text="1";
    case 2:
       cell.labelText.text="2";
    case 3:
        cell.labelText.text="3";
    case 4:
        cell.labelText.text="4";
    case 5:
        cell.labelText.text="5";
    case 6:
        cell.labelText.text="6";
    case 7:
        cell.labelText.text="7";
    case 8:
        cell.labelText.text="8";
    case 9:
        cell.labelText.text="9";
    default:
        cell.labelText.text="0";
        //print(indexPath.item)

    }

    return cell;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

When I run my code:

[image: picture]

Comment: 1. You don't need semicolons (`;`) in Swift. 2. Why do you have that `switch` statement? Just convert the number to a string and assign the value.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What code do you need help with? Please update your question with more specific details of your issue.

Comment: I am trying to load a 2D array to the collectionView because I am trying to bring my solution of Sudoku into Swift. So, I have a 2D array and load it into UICollectionView

Comment: Yes but that part is working. Please explain what your actual question/issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add those values in array

```
var array:[String] = ["1", "2" ,"3"] //and so on

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}
```

and in `cellforRow` do like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.label.text = self.array[indexpath.row]
}
```

Use collection view `didSelectItem` to get a particular cell you will tap

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         self.array[indexpath.row] = "YOUR VALUE"
         //self.collectionView.reloadData()
         self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexpath])
    }
```

**SUGGESTION:** Try to learn about MVC, MVVM and modelling 
and then try like this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49248513/5589073

Comment: This is not correct code. This updated value will be lost as soon as the cell scrolls aways. Don't update the cell here. Update the data model and then reload the given index path.

Comment: Don't use `reloadData`. Reload just the one cell.